# Delete all rows in a matrix that are not in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, delete-row

I am programming in R and I have two matrices, like this

```
a:    x1     x2                 b:   x1
      5      3                       3
      5      10                      5
      7      3                       7 
      7      140                     8
      10     152                     10
      ...    ...                     ...
```

I want to remove all rows in `b`, where `b$x1` is neither the same as any `a$x1` or `b$x1`. If the `x1` of matrix `b` is the same as any `x1` or `x2` in `a`, then it should stay in matrix `b`. The matrices also have other columns, but they are not interesting for this operation.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) on how to make your dummy data easily available for people that wants to help you. Please also show what you tried. [Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure If I've properly understood what are you asking but you can try like that

```
> a
     x1  x2
[1,]  5   3
[2,]  5  10
[3,]  7   2
[4,]  7 140
[5,] 10 152

> b
     x1
[1,]  3
[2,]  5
[3,]  7
[4,]  8
[5,] 10

> as.matrix(b[which(b %in% a[,c(1,2)])])

         [,1]
    [1,]    3
    [2,]    5
    [3,]    7
    [4,]   10
```

And bear in mind that both "a" and "b" must be matrices and furthermore, the outcome of that function will result in a matrix with less rows, you can easily expand the operation if you have more columns.

**EDIT**

OK, no big problem, but you specified that both where matrices or perhaps, I misread, whatever. I edit with the same operation with data frames but still left the matrices for anyone who could need it.

```
> subset(b, b$x1 %in% c(a$x1,a$x2))
  x1
1  3
2  5
3  7
5 10
```

You can also establish the index to be like `b[[index]]` instead of using names built-in data frame reference